# ionic auth service logout error

Tags: angular, ionic2, logout

I'm implementing a login system for my ionic app. The signup, login and logout are handled by ionics Auth-Service. Signup and login are working fine, but the logout throws an error in main.js:

```
_this.plt is null
```

The logout-Code is taken from the documentation:

```
this.auth.logout();
```

The strange thing is, that the logout is performed, but named error is shown (on debug console and as ionic error screen).

The logout button is placed inside the sidemenu of the app:

```html
<ion-menu [content]="content" *ngIf="auth.isAuthenticated()">
  <ion-header>
    <ion-toolbar>
      <ion-title>Menu</ion-title>
    </ion-toolbar>
  </ion-header>

  <ion-content>
    <ion-list>
      <button menuClose ion-item *ngFor="let p of pages" (click)="openPage(p)">
        {{p.title}}
      </button>
    </ion-list>

    <ion-fab bottom right>
      <button ion-fab mini><ion-icon name="arrow-dropleft"></ion-icon></button>
      <ion-fab-list side="left">
        <button menuClose ion-fab (click)="logout()"><ion-icon name="md-log-out"></ion-icon></button>
      </ion-fab-list>
    </ion-fab>

  </ion-content>
</ion-menu>

<ion-nav [root]="rootPage" #content swipeBackEnabled="false"></ion-nav>
```

Did anybody had the same problem or can help me find out whats the problem here?

Comment: This is still a valid issue when logging out with ionic's Auth Service. Have you found a solution, or does anyone know a work-around to this?